# Should I avoid using unnecessary db transactions (django+postgresql environment)?

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions

I'm using Django, using a Postgres DB, and I wonder:
say I have a function like this:

```
def yay_func(obj):
    log('yay')
    obj.is_yay = True
    obj.save()
```

If I wrap this function in a transaction, will I cause any strain on my db?
I checked the Django connections object, so I know another db request is made for creating a "save point", but I wonder if it's something I should consider when I'm trying to optimize my performance.

Comment: As with most things performance, it will depend alot upon how a particular function is used (how often is it used, it it a bottleneck etc.). You don't really know anything until you profile it, and find out where you can save time. The question to ask yourself is if you have a good reason to make it a transaction. If so, go for it. If it later turns out to be a performance problem, it's very easy to undo that. But before you know if it is actually causing performance issues it's just a massive waste of time worrying about it.

Comment: As the great Donald Knuth said: "premature optimization is the root of all evil"